# Integration: Taking limit first or substitution first?

Tags: integration, limits

So I need to evaluate Equation (1) where c is just a constant.

If I substitute the integral bounds first then taking the limit I will have (2).

If I take limit first then substitute the integral bounds I will have (3).

I know that (2) is correct while (3) isn't. However, I would like to know under what circumstances equation (3) will also be valid.

Thank you!

$$\begin{align*}
&\lim_{r\to 0}\int_0^{r+c}\frac1r\,dx\tag{1}\\\\
&\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r+c}r=1+\frac{c}\epsilon\tag{2}\\\\
&\int_0^c\frac1\epsilon\,dx=\frac{c}\epsilon\tag{3}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Does $\epsilon=r$? Assuming so: the left-hand side of (3) is not the result of taking the limit in (1). You would have to take the limit of both occurrences of $r$, not just one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of them is correct.

$$\begin{align*}\lim_{r\to 0}\int_0^{r+c}\frac1r\,dx&=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac1r\int_0^{r+c}dx\\
&=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac1r\left[x\right]_0^{r+c}\\
&=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac1r(r+c)\\
&=\lim_{r\to 0}\left(1+\frac{c}r\right)\\
&=1+\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{c}r\;,
\end{align*}$$

and

$$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{c}r=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }c=0\\
\text{undefined},&\text{otherwise}\;,
\end{cases}$$

so

$$\lim_{r\to 0}\int_0^{r+c}\frac1r\,dx=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }c=0\\
\text{undefined},&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$